# VueX Not detecting change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an object which has two levels of depth with two other objects :

```
$store.state.object.level1.level2
```

Both level one and level two are dynamic and I need to detect when they are defined in a `v-if`:

```
<Component v-if="$store.state.object.level1 && $store.state.object.level1.level2">
```

The statement works when Level1 becomes defined but not when level2 is defined.

Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: This sounds like the standard reactivity caveat around adding new properties to objects. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects Difficult to be sure without knowing how `level2` is being populated.

Comment: Can you please share the code from where you are creating or setting level1 and level2 inside a object

Answer (score 0):

for better or worse (probably worse) I've stopped updating state with `state.x = newX` and started using `Vue.set(state, 'x', newX)`

this resolved all my issues with getting my views updated, but somehow I have a feeling there's a better solution than this.

so in your case I would write this

```
Vue.set($store.state.object.level1, 'level2', newValueForLevel2)
```